# How does an asp.net page know which button triggered a postback?

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

I'm writing some code which mimics the effect of making a postback to a page by executing exactly the same web request that would be generated on clicking a button that triggers the page postback.

The problem is that the response from the web request is not the same as what I get when clicking on the button.

On investigating, I see that even though the Page_Load event is triggered and handled when I execute the web request, the handler for the button click is not being executed (meaning that either the event is not triggered, or it's being triggered but not handled - I'm guessing it's more likely the former case).

So my question is - **how does ASP.NET know what button has been clicked so that it can invoke the appropriate handler?**

I thought that this was done by using the __EVENTTARGET param - I have correctly set this in the post body of the web request, but this made no difference.

I looked at the decoded __VIEWSTATE argument, but I couldn't see anything obvious in there.

Can anyone provide any further help?

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, I am **not** asking how to add a click handler to a web application.

Rather, I am looking at an application that **already** has a button click event handler, and I want to know how asp.net figures out from an incoming web request what button click event handler code to invoke.

Comment: Can you give more details on how you are making the webrequest? Using C# code or jquery or javascript? Are you passing along the _Viewstate along with the web request? What error are you seeing?

Comment: I'm using C#. 

What I'm doing is that I'm making an initial request to a page, and getting back a __VIEWSTATE element in the response. Then in the web request that I generate to mimic the postback, I pass the value of this __VIEWSTATE.

I'm not seeing an error - all I see is when I put a breakpoint on the server code is that the code to handle the button click on the server is not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured this out in the end.

The request should contain a name value pair, where the name is the id of the clicked button, and the value can be '1'.

What puzzled me is that in the request generated by clicking the button, I did not see such a name value pair. Very strange indeed.

Nevertheless, adding this name value pair to my created web request caused the button click event handler code to be fired.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, an ASP.NET Button `<asp:button>` renders as an `<input type="submit" runat="server"...>` element on the form. With reference to postbacks, this button behaves differently as compared to other controls.

When clicked `<input type="submit"...>` will automatically fire a postback **without the help of ASP.NET** (try it in an .htm). You can determine which button was clicked by viewing the parameters of the POST body. The button name and its value (Text prop.) will be sent as parameters. __EVENTTARGET is not in the picture and should be null. Also, there will be ONLY ONE button control in the list of parameters according to the specification (the one that was clicked). So now you know which button was clicked.

Then what is the use of __EVENTTARGET?

Other controls, like `<asp:DropDownList>` which render as `SELECT`, do not fire a postback when clicked, but simply raise an onChange javascript event. If you want to handle the event on the server side via the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, ASP.NET will have to do some extra work for you. If you set AutoPostBack = True for the DropDownList, ASP.NET will capture the original onChange JS event and hookup a custom __doPostBack JS function that is responsible for populating the __EVENTTARGET and **explicitly** submitting the form. You can now determine the control that triggered the the postback by examining __EVENTTARGET.

Hope this helps a bit !

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question, but I can tell you how to find out.

Add a line to your page_load: Request.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\request.txt", true); (for an example).

Then click your button to effect the postback.

Then read the contents of request.txt. Is there anything useful or interesting in there?

Comment: Thanks, Wozza. I'll give it a go and let you know what I find out.

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind, you have to have an event to process, and that event has to have `Handles ButtonName.Click`

IE:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ''# Process everything you want to process when Button2 gets clicked
End Sub
```

Alternatively, in your button you can have `OnClick` set in the markup.

```
<asp:button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Click Me" />
```

Because the button is set to `runat="server"`, .NET will do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Hi Rockinthesixstring, as I said to Cylon Cat above, I don't want to handle the click event - I just want to figure out why the existing click event is not firing when I invoke a web request that is identical to the request that is invoked on a button click. If I knew what exactly asp.net was looking for in the web request in order to invoke the click handler code, then I would add this to the web request - hence my original question about how the asp.net parses the web request that is sent to figure out which handler to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of easy ways to create an event handler for a button. In layout mode, double-click on the button. Or, also in layout mode, select the button, open the Properties window, click the "lightning bolt" icon, and see a list of events the control can trigger. Double-click on the event you want.

When you do one of these things, Visual Studio, will create the event handler in your code-behind, and wire up the event.

The button event handler runs after page load, and after page validation if you're using ASP.NET validators.

Comment: Hi Cylon Cat, I **don't** want to create an event handler for a button. Rather, I want to exercise server code in an web application which is supposed to handle a button click. I want to do this by invoking a web request which is identical to the web request that is generated when a button is clicked. I believe that doing so should cause the button click handler code to be called, but this is not happening. So I want to know what asp.net looks for in a web request in order figure out what event handler code should be invoked.

Comment: Web requests are handled very differently from button clicks, so if you want to treat this as a web request, you can go with two ways. One is by using Page Methods, and the other is by creating a web service. I havent used Page Methods, but they are AJAX-callable methods within a page, and you'll need an asp:ScriptManager tag specifying that you're going to use Page Methods. If you create a web service, the service code will run in-session in ASP.NET, and have access to session variables. You can code a service reference in the asp:ScriptManager; that makes the service callable from JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

It looks like really only the **__EVENTTARGET** value needs to be posted with the ID of the button you want to click.  You have to set **EnableEventValidation="false"** or ASP.NET will throw an error.  Check out this example.  Plain html page, posts to asp.net page, simulating a button click on that page, which should be similar to what you are trying to do.

HTML page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form action="Default.aspx" method="post">
    <input value="cmdSubmit" name="__EVENTTARGET" type="hidden" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASP.NET Page with Button to Click (Default.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  EnableEventValidation="false"    %>
<script runat="server">

    protected void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        litResult.Text = "Submit button clicked";
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Literal ID="litResult" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Literal>
    <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" ID="cmdSubmit" EnableViewState="false" runat="server"
        OnClick="cmdSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chris, I might generate the javascript - but how would this answer my question of how asp.net knows how to trigger particular event handling code?

Comment: It appears to me that the javascript is setting the value of the __EVENTTARGET hidden field with the ID of the control that is being clicked, and then submitting the form.  But there is probably more to it than that, like maybe the viewstate field cannot be empty to indicate that it is a postback.

Comment: That's a good point, Chris, and that's what I thought myself. I checked the __EVENTTARGET field of the request that was generated on clicking the button, and it had the id of the button that was clicked. I then ensured that my request had the same __EVENTTARGET value, but this did not appear to trigger the button click event handler. So maybe there is more to it. I wish someone could shed more light here...

Comment: I did some testing and updated my answer. I was able to post to the asp.net page from a plain html page and trigger the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Shoko,

ASP.net postbacks can be tricky, but you should take a look at this article using the __doPostBack() javascript function for some insight.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1521-How-call-Postback-from-Javascript.aspx

HTH,

Mike